# Angularjs file upload directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a file upload directive to use in forms.

```
angular.module("app")
    .directive("myFileUpload", [function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: '<input type="file" multiple class="form-control" placeholder="Select file">',
            scope: {
                files: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {

                element.change(function (event) {
                    scope.files = event.target.files;
                    event.preventDefault();
                });

            }
        }
    }]);
```

I can use this directive in somewhere of my application.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input ng-model="myform.title">
    <my-file-upload files="myform.files"></my-file-upload>
</div>
```

And I want to list that selected files like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input ng-model="myform.title">
    <my-file-upload files="myform.files"></my-file-upload>
    <p ng-repeat="item in myform.files">{{item.filename}}</p>
</div>
```

If I do not enter text in input `myform.title`, the files does not list.

Comment: Try calling `scope.$apply()` after assigning `scope.files`

Answer (score 1):

the callback of

```
element.change
```

happens outside of the "angular-world". you will need to let angular know that "something happened"
try this instead

```js
element.change(function (event) {
  scope.files = event.target.files;
  event.preventDefault();
  scope.$apply();
});
```